Get location updates based on time interval or min distance in Android(whichever comes first)
I've been working on an android application in jetpack compose that tracks user's live location and allows group members to track/check each others live locations and journey routes.
Currently, according to the code, the location updates are received at an interval of every 10 seconds, but it could potentially drain user's battery. So i want a solution such that i get location updates at an interval of 1 minute or on distance update of 10 meters which ever comes first!
Current LocationRequest builder:
private const val LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000L

private fun createRequest(): LocationRequest =
    LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
        .apply {
            setGranularity(Granularity.GRANULARITY_PERMISSION_LEVEL)
            setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
            setWaitForAccurateLocation(true)
        }.build()

I tried applying setMinUpdateDistanceMeters(10f) in LocationRequest.Builder(), but the issue while using it is when user stops moving, the distance is 0, so even after 5-10mins, there is no location update received i.e., time interval is ignored.
Here is the overall code for LocationManager.kt class:
private const val LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000L

@Singleton
class LocationManager @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) {

    private var request: LocationRequest
    private var locationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)

    init {
        request = createRequest()
    }

    suspend fun getLastLocation(): Location? {
        if (!context.hasCoarseLocationPermission) return null
        return locationClient.lastLocation.await()
    }

    private val locationUpdatePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
        val intent = Intent(context, LocationUpdateReceiver::class.java)
        intent.action = ACTION_LOCATION_UPDATE
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
            )
        } else {
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }
    }

    private fun createRequest(): LocationRequest =
        LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
            .apply {
                setGranularity(Granularity.GRANULARITY_PERMISSION_LEVEL)
                setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                setWaitForAccurateLocation(true)
            }.build()

    internal fun startLocationTracking() {
        if (context.hasFineLocationPermission) {
            locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, locationUpdatePendingIntent)
        }
    }

    internal fun stopLocationTracking() {
        if (!context.isBackgroundLocationPermissionGranted) {
            locationClient.flushLocations()
            locationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationUpdatePendingIntent)
        }
    }

    fun startService() {
        context.startService(Intent(context, BackgroundLocationService::class.java))
    }

    fun stopService() {
        context.stopService(Intent(context, BackgroundLocationService::class.java))
    }
}

The project is open-source, so if any other reference is required, you guys can checkout the repository: GroupTrack
